# Prove $ab\leq(1/p)a^p+(1/q)b^q$ using concavity of ln

Tags: real-analysis

For $1\leq p < \infty$, we equip the Banach space $l^p=\{x= (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, \ldots) :\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^p<\infty\} $ with the norm $‖x‖_{l^p}=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x^n|^p)^{1/p}$ . Now, let $1< p, q <\infty$ be such that $1/p+1/q= 1$.

Use the concavity of the $\ln$ function to prove that for every $a, b >0$, $ab\leq(1/p)a^p+(1/q)b^q$.

Proof idea:
$$
\begin{align} 
ab&=e^{\ln(ab)}\\&=e^{\ln(a)+\ln(b)}\\&=e^{(\frac{1}{p}p)\ln(a)+(\frac{1}{q}q)\ln(b)}\\&=e^{(\frac{1}{p})\ln(a^p)+(\frac{1}{q})\ln(b^q)}\\&\leq \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)e^{\ln(a^p)}+\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)e^{\ln(b^q)}
\end{align} 
$$

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: What is the $*$ operation, just a product by a scalar? And what is the link with $l^p$spaces ... are $a$ and $b$ sequences?

Comment: You can use the same argument using concavity of $\ln:$ $$\ln(ab)=\frac1p\ln(a^p)+\frac1q\ln(b^q)\leq \ln\left(\frac1pa^p+\frac1qb^q\right)$$ and then use that $\ln$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Yes multiplication between scalars. I will re-edit